# Serial communication between linux and windows

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

I am sending data bytes from linux to windows in serial RS232 then everything is ok, only i have to handle 0xa send from linux, because windows read it as 0xd + 0xa.
but when i am sending data bytes from windows to linux some bytes are replaced as -
 windows send - 0xd linux receive 0xa
windows send - 0x11 linux receive garbage tyte value in integer  something 8200

plese explain what goes wrong when I send data from windows to Linux.
thanks in advance

Windows serial port initialize

```
char *pcCommPort = "COM1";
    hCom = CreateFile( TEXT("COM1"),
                       GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                       0,    // must be opened with exclusive-access
                       NULL, // no security attributes
                       OPEN_EXISTING, // must use OPEN_EXISTING
                       0,    // not overlapped I/O
                       NULL  // hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices
                       );
fSuccess = GetCommState(hCom, &dcb);
 FillMemory(&dcb, sizeof(dcb),0);


    dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcb);
    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_115200;     // set the baud rate
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;             // data size, xmit, and rcv
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;        // no parity bit
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;    // one stop bit
    dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = false;

    fSuccess = SetCommState(hCom, &dcb);
 buff_success = SetupComm(hCom, 1024, 1024);
COMMTIMEOUTS cmt;
    // ReadIntervalTimeout in ms
    cmt.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1000;
    cmt.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1000;
    cmt.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=1000;
    timeout_flag = SetCommTimeouts(hCom, &cmt);
```

windows write serial-

```
WriteFile(hCom, buffer, len, &write, NULL);
```

Linux serial initialize-

```
_fd_port_no = open("//dev//ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
tcgetattr(_fd_port_no, &options);
        cfsetispeed(&options, B115200);
        cfsetospeed(&options, B115200);
        options.c_cflag |= (CS8);
        options.c_cflag|=(CLOCAL|CREAD);
        options.c_cflag &=~PARENB;
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
        options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
        options.c_iflag |= (IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
        options.c_cflag &= ~ CRTSCTS;
        tcsetattr(_fd_port_no, TCSANOW, &options);
```

read serial linux-

```
while(read(_fd_port_no,buffer+_buffer_len,sizeof(buffer))>0)
    {
        _buffer_len = _buffer_len+sizeof(buffer);

    }
```

Yes, as i told from Linux to windows only NL/CR problem detected but i solved it by byte replacing,
but do you have any idea about serila data send from windows to Linux (byte replacement policy).
Actually I have to send 200 KB file in 200 bytes blocks over serial so which byte could be replaced if send from Windows to Linux

Comment: So you're sending raw bytes, and not text?  Show the code that sends and receives; as little code as possible of course.

Comment: Note that `0x0a` is new-line, and `0x0d` is carriage-return.  Sounds like typical NL/CR issue.

Comment: If you are sending a file from windows, have you opened that file in text mode or binary mode ? Make sure all your serial settings are the same on both ends, e.g. you seem to have XON/XOFF on the linux side, but not on the windows side (Dont use XON/XOFF)

Comment: I opened file in binary mode

Comment: ok this thing i will check and thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `ReadFile` and `WrietFile` on Windows and `read` and `write` in Linux, it shouldn't really matter what the line-endings are, other than "you have to translate it at some point after receiving it.

This doesn't look right:

```
while(read(_fd_port_no,buffer+_buffer_len,sizeof(buffer))>0)
{
    _buffer_len = _buffer_len+sizeof(buffer);

}
```

You should take into account the size of the read returned by `read`.

And if `sizeof(buffer)` is the actual buffer you are reading into, adding `+_buffer_len`, when `_buffer_len >= sizeof(buffer)` will write outside the buffer.

Also slightly worried about this:

```
    options.c_iflag |= (IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    options.c_cflag &= ~ CRTSCTS;
```

Are you SURE you want a XOFF/CTRL-S (0x13) to stop flow? Usually that means that data with CTRL-S in it won't be allowed - which may not be an issue when sending text data, but if you ever need to send binary data it certainly will be. IXOFF also means that the other end will have to respond to XOFF and XON (CTRL-Q, 0x11) to stop/start the flow of data. Typically, we don't want this in modern systems....

Using RTS/CTS should be safe if you have the wiring correct between the two ends.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to  flush before reading the flux from a serial port

```
tcflush(_fd_port_no TCIFLUSH);
```

furthemore Have you tried to see the flux with a console using the commande
    cat < dev/ttyS0 ?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid line ending conversions you might need to add:

```
options.c_iflag &= ~IGNCR;  // turn off ignore \r 
options.c_iflag &= ~INLCR;  // turn off translate \n to \r 
options.c_iflag &= ~ICRNL;  // turn off translate \r to \n

options.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR;  // turn off map \n  to \r\n
options.c_oflag &= ~OCRNL;  // turn off map \r to \n 
options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;  // turn off implementation defined output processing
```

Also, the following line:

```
options.c_iflag |= (IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
```

Will enable XON/XOFF processing, so the tty driver will process Ctrl-S (XOFF) and Ctrl-Q (XON) characters as flow control (which is probably why you see somethign unexpected when sending 0x11, which is Ctrl-Q). I'd expect that you'd want to turn those bits off:

```
options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
```

In fact, I think you might want to call `cfmakeraw()` after calling `tcgetattr()` which should disable all special handling of input and output characters.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all

This Change Solved my problem

```
fd_port_no = open("//dev//ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
tcgetattr(_fd_port_no, &options);
        cfsetispeed(&options, B115200);
        cfsetospeed(&options, B115200);
        options.c_cflag |= (CS8);
        options.c_cflag|=(CLOCAL|CREAD);
        options.c_cflag &=~PARENB;
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
        options.c_cflag &= ~ CRTSCTS;
        options.c_iflag |= (IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
        options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ISIG | ECHO | ECHONL | ECHOE | ECHOK);
        options.c_cflag &= ~ OPOST;
        tcsetattr(_fd_port_no, TCSANOW, &options);
```

Comment: But technically dont know how it worked but my problem is solved and tested well

Comment: actualy sever and client machine shifted to linux so  this code worked on linix to linux serial communication.